# decomposing an expression into absolutely positive terms

Tags: factorization

I have a big ugly expression which, for unimportant (here) reasons, must be greater than or equal to zero. It is formed from terms which themselves are greater than or equal to zero.

As such it should be possible to rearrange it such that I only have terms in even powers or that are pre multiplied by only positive instances of the comprising positive terms..

i.e.

```
(k1+k2)((k3-k4)^2)
```

but not

```
(k1-k2)((k3-k4)^2)
```

or

```
(k1+k2)((k3-k4)^3)
```

and so on.

Is there any way to get *Mathematica* to decompose my expression into terms like the first of the above three so I can prove that my expression is positive?

Thanks.

Edit: the expression is:

```
(1/( (kx1 ky1 + kc1 (kx1 + ky1)))) *
(kx^2 ky1 + 2 kc^2 (kx1 + ky1) + 2 kc1^2 (kx1 + ky1) + 2 kc (kx1 (ky - 2 ky1) + kx ky1) + kx1 ((ky - ky1)^2 + (-2 kx + kx1) ky1) + kc1 (kx^2 + kx1^2 - 2 kx1 (ky - 2 ky1) + (ky - ky1)^2 -  4 kc (kx1 + ky1) - 2 kx (kx1 + ky1)))
```

The prefactor can probably be ignored for these purposes. The variables kx,ky,kc,kx1,ky1,kc1 are all greater than or equal to zero. I factored it by hand into positive terms but would always get a couple of remainder terms so would like to just get it done by *Mathematica*

Comment: I get this coming back to me " Factoring multivariate polynomials with respect to a modulus is not yet implemented; FactorSquareFree will be used instead."

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not sure what it has done, it has given me a single expression composed of several terms all of which have a single variable squared in them. The overall output expression is not a factor of the input and it also doesn't contain all of the terms in the input that had square terms in them. I suspect factor is not going to work particularly well as I think Mathematica would have simplified if possible, I suspect it needs to be broken up into several non-negative expressions.

Comment: Maybe you have to use `Expand` before `Factor`. But without an example expression (not as big as your real one, but with similar terms) it's hard to guess what will solve your problem.

Comment: Already tried that, but got the same result. I can try editing the post to include my expression. It's not huge, but just cumbersome to deal with IRL and has 6 variables (all positive).