# Factorize into only positive terms, when values are known to be probabilities

Tags: notation, appearance, styling

I have a large term (a small snippet of which is below as an example) that I am aiming to prove is positive. I know that all the involved values are probabilities and in particular, they lie in (0, 1). By default, the factorization seems to assume that the values are greater than one, and so factorizes as (-1 + x) or (-1 + q). I'd like to somehow assume (I've tried using "Assuming"), that they are between 0 and 1, and factorize into only positive terms such as - (1 - x) or - (1 - q), to make it easier to parse and avoid errors on my part. Is there some way to do so?

`(q x (-1 + \[Alpha]) (-1 + \[Gamma]) - (-1 + x \[Alpha]) (-1 + x \[Gamma]))`

[Related but unanswered question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96360/decomposing-an-expression-into-absolutely-positive-terms)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This expression appears to be negative. Which can be shown using `FindInstance` and observing there is no positive case, like so: `In[227]:= 
ee = (q *x*(-1 + alf) (-1 + gam) - (-1 + x *alf) (-1 + x *gam));

In[228]:= FindInstance[{ee > 0, 0 < q < 1, 0 < x < 1, 0 < alf < 1, 
  0 < gam < 1}, {q, x, alf, gam}]

Out[228]= {}`

Comment: If I am trying to make a complicated expression easier to parse and avoid errors on my part then I have found that carefully inspecting the output of `LogicalExpand[Reduce[0<=complicatedexpression<=1&&0<=q<=1&&0<=α<=1&&0<=γ<=1]]` has been helpful. I can look at each case and verify that they are correct and have been handled. It would be more convenient if that gave `0<α&&α<=1` as `0<α<=1` and if it sorted all the cases into order by variable name, but I have not found a way to consistently do that. Hopefully this might help you.

Comment: @Daniel: That wasn't the entire function, just a subset of it.

Regardless, FindInstance is quite helpful! I had been using NMinimize, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = q x (-1 + α) (-1 + γ) - (-1 + x α) (-1 + x γ);

expr2 = (expr /. Plus[-1, z_] :> -HoldForm[ Plus[1, -z]]) // 
  ReleaseHold

(* q x (1 - α) (1 - γ) - (1 - x α) (1 - x γ) *)
```

Verifying that `expr2` is equivalent to `expr`

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

However, any simplification will revert to the undesired form

```
expr2

(* q x (1 - α) (1 - γ) - (1 - x α) (1 - x γ) *)

expr2 // Simplify

(* q x (-1 + α) (-1 + γ) - (-1 + x α) (-1 + x γ) *)
```

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I had been looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

MMA has built in formatting rules that will always put the -1 at the beginning. To circumvent this, you must replace the (-1+..) term by something wrapped in "HoldForm". This will then no more evaluate and as the "HoldForm" is not displayed you will get the display you want.

Here is an example:

```
Simplify[(q x (-1+α) (-1+γ) - (-1+x α) (-1+x γ))] /. (-1 + x_) -> HoldForm@(x - 1`)

(q x (-1 + α) (-1 + γ) - (-1 + x α) (-1 + x γ))
```